# Where has TextBlock Background property gone in UWP?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I need to change the Background of a TextBlock in UWP but the Background property no longer exists. What is the solution for this?

This don't work...

```
                    <TextBlock Text="Exceptions Log"
                               FontSize="10"
                               Background="Red" // This is invalid
                               />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Just put it inside a Grid or a Border or something else...

```
<Border Background="Red">
    <TextBlock Text="Exceptions Log"
               FontSize="10" />
</Border>
```

Comment: Thank you igrali. I did think of wrapping it in a Border but was also wondering if I was doing something wrong as Background does exist as a property on a TextBloxk in WPF. Thank you for the speedy response.